# How to connect Ruby to SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, odbc

I've been trying to connect my Ruby on Rails web app to my SQL Server database, I've looked everywhere on the internet especially Stack Overflow and can't seem to get it to work, even tried odbc. Any ideas/ things I can do to make it work?

Comment: You can connect to a SQL Database using Ruby on Windows, Linux, or Mac. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ruby/ruby-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: This is rather broad and hard to answer. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What did you try up to now? (beside the information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138013/error-with-rake-dbmigrate-using-tiny-tds-and-sqlserver-adapter - there is no need to open new questions with the same topic, but less information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a `dlib connection` with the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  database: sqlserverdatabase
  host: host
  port: port
  username: username
  password: password
```