# Why can't the file tiny_tds.so be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tiny-tds

I have written a Ruby on Rails app on Windows 10 that uses `SQLite3` in development but needs to use `SQLServer` in production. I am using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.1.4.

I included the `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gems in the `Gemfile` and ran `'bundle install'`. This seems to have completed successfully. I then ran `'rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production'` and got the error `'LoadError: cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds'`.

The complete error message output is below. Can you please tell me what the problem may be and what I can do to fix it.

```
$ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds
c:/Sites/turkeytote/config/application.rb:7:in <top (required)>' c:/Sites/turkeytote/Rakefile:4:inrequire_relative'
c:/Sites/turkeytote/Rakefile:4:in <top (required)>' bin/rails:4:inrequire'
bin/rails:4:in `

'
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found. - c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/2.3/tiny_tds.so
```

Comment: Where are you hosting your app ? Does the instalaltion went smoothly (no failed gem install etc..) ?

Comment: The app is hosted on the company intranet. I tested it locally with a SQLite3 database and it works fine. The problem is when I try to use the SQLServer database in production.

Comment: I am still not an expert in Rails but I host my app through Heroku and when I migrate I type on the Heroku console and don't have to even mention the environment. It is implicit. When you do `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` are you doing it on the company server and not your local machine ? (sorry if this sound trivial but better check)

Comment: I changed the tiny_tds gem to version 1.3.0 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently, and it turns out that the issue was due to the Ruby DevKit not being included in my Windows system and user PATH variables.

I was using the Windows Ruby 2.3 Rails Installer from http://railsinstaller.org/en, which installs Ruby (and related libraries) at the C:\RailsInstaller location by default.

If you open a command prompt and browse to C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit, then run the "devkitvars.bat" file, this will add the relevant paths to your PATH variable:
C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\bin;

After doing this, tiny_tds worked, and my `rails db:migrate` command finally worked successfully.

Note: This is *not* a permanent fix. To fix the issue permanently, you need to actually edit your Windows PATH settings.

**Setting your PATH (on Windows 10 and Windows 8)**

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and
   select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not
   exist, click New.
5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System
   Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment
   variable.
6. The PATH variable should include this string: "C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\bin;"
7. Click OK.
8. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
9. Open a new command prompt and type `path` to make sure that your changes are in effect.